# I can't get my DeleteCommand to work in ASP.net 4.0 VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, listview

I have a ListView that lists features of a product on my website. I included an image button that is supposed to delete the specific feature, but my DeleteCommand won't do it. I have looked in my database, and the record is still there. Is there some code I need to add to the CodeBehind file to get this to work?

```
  <!-- Features --> 
 <asp:TabPanel id="tab1" class="infoHeader" runat="server" HeaderText="Features" DataKeyNames="MarketingID">
    <HeaderTemplate>Features</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul class="info">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvFeatures" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFeatures">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <li><%#Eval("FeatureTitle")%>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteFeatureButton" runat="server" Style="float:right;" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="../../images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" OnCommand="ImageButton1_Command" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this feature?')" />
          </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>   

   Protected Sub ImageButton1_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
    If TypeOf DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).Parent Is ListViewDataItem Then
        Dim item As ListViewDataItem = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).Parent, ListViewDataItem)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            lvFeatures.Items.RemoveAt(item.DisplayIndex)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

<!-- Gets all current features of this product -->
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsFeatures" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT m.MarketingID, f.FeatureID, f.FeatureTitle FROM Feature f INNER JOIN Marketing m ON m.MarketingData = f.FeatureID WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 3 and m.ProductID = @ProductID"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Marketing WHERE MarketingID = @MarketingID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="id" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="MarketingID" QueryStringField="id" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete an item using the SqlDataSource, you have to do it like this:

Change the delete portion of your SqlDataSource control. Remove the QueryStringParameter from the DeleteParameters. You shouldn't have any parameters for the Delete:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsFeatures" runat="server"                 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>"                 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString.ProviderName %>"                 
    SelectCommand="SELECT m.MarketingID, f.FeatureID, f.FeatureTitle FROM Feature f INNER JOIN Marketing m ON m.MarketingData = f.FeatureID WHERE m.MarketingTypeID = 3 and m.ProductID = @ProductID"                
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Marketing WHERE MarketingID = @MarketingID">                
    <SelectParameters>                
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ProductID" QueryStringField="id" />                
    </SelectParameters>                               
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Add MarketingID as a data key to your ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFeatures" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFeatures" DataKeyNames="MarketingID">    
    <ItemTemplate>    
        <li>    
            <%#Eval("FeatureTitle")%>    
            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteFeatureButton" runat="server" Style="float:right;" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="../../images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this feature?');" />        
        </li>    
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:ListView>
```

To debug the code before the delete occurs, add an OnDeleting event handler to the SqlDataSource control. You can then set a breakpoint before the delete to verify the code that will be executed.

```
protected void dsFeatures_Deleting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string commandText = e.Command.CommandText;
}
```

Comment: @jlg: Try this. This should work with the SqlDataSource control.

Comment: When i get rid of the DeleteParameters it throws an error saying I need to define the scalar variable @MarketingID, I've also tried changing the QueryStringParameter to just Parameter but that still doesn't let me delete anything.

Comment: If I want to debug, where should I put the breakpoint? So far it hasn't stopped at my breakpoint

Comment: I tried this on another one of the ListViews I have on my page and it allows deleting, I am going to continue adding this code to every LV on my page and compare them with the Features LV. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I don't think you'll hit any breakpoints doing it this way, because there's no code behind. Add an OnDeleting event handler for the SqlDataSource control. See edited answer.

Comment: Ok so it only works with the one ListView. All the rest of them want the dang @MarketingID scalar variable to be defined, so I add the deleteparameters and nothing deletes. I am giving up for today and going home. I need a break.

Comment: @jlg: That's why I don't like or use data source controls. You don't know what's going on under the hood. You shouldn't need to define any delete parameters. It should use the data key of the ListView to automatically assign the MarketingID to the delete command. It should work just the way I have it in my answer. What I'm not sure of is whether it will automatically rebind the ListView after the delete so that you can see the changes.

Comment: I ran through the site again this morning and now most of the DeleteCommands work. I re-configured the datasources, typing in the same delete statements as before and the configurator added delete parameters before the select parameters and it worked for all of the datasources that use the MarketingID as DataKeyNames! Thanks so much for all the help last week @James!

Answer (score 2):

If you attach a datakeynames property  to the listview it should wire that up for you automatically.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvFeatures" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFeatures"
 DataKeyNames="MarketingID">
```

This is assuming that the id is part of the data set. You'll have to change the paramter in the `<DeleteParameters>` to just a regular parameter, not a querystring param.

Comment: <asp:ListView ID="lvFeatures" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFeatures" DataKeyNames="MarketingID"> - It still doesn't delete anything.

Comment: did you change the delete param as well?

Comment: <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="MarketingID" />
</DeleteParameters> Like this?

Comment: No, you don't need any delete parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually assign the command event handler. You should also assign the index to the command argument.

**EDIT**: Just noticed that the ImageButton is contained in a ListView, which is contained in a TabPanel. Revised code to delete item from ListView.

---

### Original method for removing the item from list

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>' OnCommand="ImageButton1_Command" ...>
```

In the *code behind*:

**EDIT**: Removed c# code and included VB.NET syntax
**EDIT**: Changed method from private to protected

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName.ToUpper() = "DELETE" Then           
       lvFeatures.Items.RemoveAt(DirectCast(e.CommandArgument, Integer))
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Added alternative methods for deleting item, because Container.ItemIndex doesn't seem to be working properly in his code

---

### Alternative ways of removing the item from the list

Remove the command argument altogether, like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"  OnCommand="ImageButton1_Command" ...>
```

Alternative #1: Remove item directly

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    If TypeOf DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).Parent Is ListViewDataItem Then
        Dim item As ListViewDataItem = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).Parent, ListViewDataItem)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            lvFeatures.Items.Remove(item)                
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternative #2: Remove item at display index

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
    If TypeOf DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).Parent Is ListViewDataItem Then
        Dim item As ListViewDataItem = TryCast(DirectCast(sender, ImageButton).Parent, ListViewDataItem)
        If item IsNot Nothing Then                               
            lvFeatures.Items.RemoveAt(item.DisplayIndex)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I added OnCommand="DeleteFeatureButton_Command" and I got an error when I tried to delete. It says DeleteFeatureButton_Command is not a member of this page. Do I need VB code too?

Comment: You need to add the event handler to the code behind too. I'll repost with VB code in a minute.

Comment: Yes you need to add the vb code in your codebehind, what James has given you is a c# version of it. you can convert it easily tho by going to http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Sorry to post the vb code in other answer, i removed it and went to update your answer with the vb code but you already got to it. Good work.

Comment: @Dylan Hayes: Thank you. I appreciate you're help in trying to improve my answer. It was tagged as VB, so I should have picked up on that. I'm just always thinking in C# :)

Comment: I would convert it but since the tab1.Items.Remove line isn't correct, it won't let me do the conversion.

Comment: What is the tab panel? What control library is it in?

Comment: Is this part of the Ajax toolkit? Shouldn't it be in a TabContainer?

Comment: Ok, most of it is fine except for the tab1.Items, it says that is not a part of the AJAXControlToolkit. It is inside of a listview that is inside of a tabpanel

Comment: @jlg: Revised answer to delete from ListView. See edited answer.

Comment: Specified cast is not valid....lvFeatures.Items.RemoveAt(DirectCast(e.CommandArgument, Integer))

Comment: Make sure you added the CommandArgument to the ImageButton in the ASPX. The example is shown in my code.

Comment: 'ItemIndex' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem'.

Comment: @JamesJohnson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2907/discussion-between-jlg-and-james-johnson)